# TagPrefix containing StrongKey

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, visual-studio

I'm debbuging a web application that has a WebSite and a class library containg web controls. My WebSite, at design-time references the assembly with a Project Reference and Visual Studio automatically populates the Toolbox with the controls found in my class library.

The problem is : When I drag them to the ASPx designer, Visual Studio automatically creates a TagPrefix ignoring the my class library's strong key. This is a problem for me because when I publish this website, this class library will be the Global Assembly Cache and it won't be found if the TagPrefix doesn't properly reference it.

Any idea about how to force visual studio to consider my assembly's strong key when creating the tag prefix?

Thanks.

Comment: What if you use an assembly reference instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you added the [TagPrefix attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.tagprefixattribute.aspx) to your class library?

From MSDN

```
[assembly:TagPrefix("CustomControls", "custom")]


namespace CustomControls
{

    // Simple custom control
    public class MyCS_Control : Control
```

You should also check out the [toolbox data attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.toolboxdataattribute.aspx)

```
namespace CustomControls
{

  [ ToolboxData("<{0}:MyLabel Text='MyLabel' BorderColor='Yellow' BackColor='Magenta' BorderWidth = '10'  runat='server'></{0}:MyLabel>") ]    
  public class MyLabel : Label 
  {
```

And lastly, register your assemblies in the web.config

```
<system.web>
    ...
    <pages>
       ...
       <controls>
           ...
           <add tagPrefix="yourPrefix"
             namespace="MyAssembly.Some.Namespace"
             assembly="MyAssembly" />
           ...
```

Rebuild your project then drag one of your controls onto the page.

Comment: the assembly attribute could work for this exact problem but it doesn't. The toolbox data attribute doesn't have anything to do with my problem. To register my assemblies in the web.config, in the other hand, solves the above mentioned problem, since I can always use the fully qualified assembly name including the strong key. I can use it with both project reference and GAC reference.